# Seaborn heatmap fails to render in webpage

Tags: python, django, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using Seaborn for some visualizations in a Django web app.

Everything is fine when I view the heatmap in iPython notebook:

```
fig,ax1=plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=400)
sns.heatmap(df,cmap='RdBu_r',cbar=False,ax=ax1)
```

I want to display the same heatmap on a webpage.

Here is the end of the plot function that generates the figure object with Seaborn heatmap:

```
 fig,ax1=plt.subplots(1,1,dpi=400)
 sns.heatmap(df,cmap='RdBu_r',cbar=False, ax=ax1)
 canvas=FigureCanvas(fig)
 response=HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
 canvas.print_png(response)
 return response
```

The plot fails.

It returns this error: `"Cannot get window extent w/o renderer"`

The error is traced to: `seaborn/utils.py`

```
    374. bboxes = [l.get_window_extent() for l in labels]
```

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: What backend do you have set?  If you're going to display the plot on a webpage, you probably need to output it to an image file and then display that.